# How can I apply NSPredicate to the PHFetchResult? I am trying to fetch all the screenshots of device whose creation date >= timestamp(or NSDate)

Tags: ios, swift, photosframework

I tried and succeeded in applying NSPredicate to:

```
PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithMediaType(PHAssetMediaType.Image, options: fetchOptions)
```

but the app crashes when I try to apply NSPredicate to:

```
PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(PHAssetCollectionType.Album, subtype: PHAssetCollectionSubtype.SmartAlbumScreenshots, options: fetchOptions)
```

App crashes with the following exception

> 'Unsupported predicate in fetch options: creationDate >= CAST(475353000.000000, "NSDate")'

Anybody can help me with this? Basically I want to fetch the screenshots taken by the device and get only those screenshots taken after a specific NSDate.

Comment: Add fetchOptions creation code.